# Dynamic table name in join query alias in Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, alias

How to alias a table name in `Laravel 5`?

```
$data['recent_reviews'] = $reviews_table_name::where('source', 'LIKE', '%YELP%')->orderby('reviews_'.$l_state.'.id', 'desc')
    ->leftJoin($res_tbl_name, 'reviews_'.$l_state.'.restaurant_id', '=', $res_tbl_name.'.id')
    ->take(6)
    ->get();
```

Actually i need the table name alias like below.

```
$res_tbl_name AS r
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try as given below:

```
$data['recent_reviews'] = $reviews_table_name::where('source', 'LIKE', '%YELP%')->orderby('reviews_'.$l_state.'.id', 'desc')
    ->leftJoin("$res_tbl_name as r", 'reviews_'.$l_state.'.restaurant_id', '=', $res_tbl_name.'.id')
    ->take(6)
    ->get();
```

And then use 'r' wherever you used $res_tbl_name

Comment: also in the join itself `->leftJoin("$res_tbl_name as r", 'reviews_'.$l_state.'.restaurant_id', '=', 'r.id')`